Bilinear forms, endomorphisms and skew symmetric matrices
Let $(V, g)$ be an inner product space and $f$ and endomorphism of $V$ such that
$$
g(u,f(v)) = -g(f(u),v),\ \ \text{for all}\ u,v \in V.
$$
Prove that
a) $\ker(f)$ and $Im (f)$ are orthogonal subspaces.
b) $V = \ker (f) \oplus Im (f)$.
c) If $B$ is an orthonormal basis of $(V,g)$ then the matrix of $f$ with respect to $B$ is skew-symmetric.
My solution:
a) Suppose that $u \in \ker (f)$ and $v\in Im (f)$, so that $v = f(w), w\in V$. Then
$$
g(u,v) = g(u,f(v)) = -g(f(u),v) = -g(0,v) = 0.
$$
This shows that $\ker (f)$ and $Im (f)$ are orthogonal.
b) Since $f$ is an endomorphism, we have $V = \ker (f) + Im (f)$. Moreover, if $v \in \ker (f) \cap Im (f)$, then $f(v) = 0$ and $v = f(w), w \in V$, so
$$
g(v, v) = g(v, f(w)) = 0
$$
where the last equality comes from $(a)$. Since $g$ is an inner product, it is positive definite, therefore the equality forces $v = 0$. It follows that
$$
V = \ker (f) \oplus Im (f).
$$
c) Suppose that $u, v \in V$ and denote $u_{B} = X,\ v_{B} = Y$ to their coordinate vectors with respect to $B$ and let $M_{B}(g)$ and $M (f, B)$ be the matrices of $g$ and $f$ with respect to $B$. Note that since $B$ is an orthonormal basis, we have $M_{B}(g) = I$. Thus,
$$
g(f(u),v) = (M(f,B)X)^{t}IY = X^{t}M(f,B)^{t}Y
$$
and
$$
-g(u,f(v)) = -X^{t}M(f,B)Y = X^{t}(-M(f,B))Y.
$$
So
$$
X^{t}M(f,B)^{t}Y = X^{t}(-M(f,B)Y
$$
for every $u_{B}, y_{B}$. This means that
$$
M(f,B)^{t} = -M(f,B),
$$
which says that $M(f,B)$ is skew-symmetric, completing the proof. Is it correct? I thin in part b I can make it a bit shorter.

Ok, I’ve just added it.

Please take a careful look at the text of the solution-verification tag. A question with that tag must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.
